# text printed twice on the same page

Tags: python, python-2.7, reportlab, pypdf

I have an issue with my generated pdf, the generated pdf file has 4 pages and I use an existing pdf with two pages. I have to write some text using `pyPD2` and `reportlab`.

When I use`getPage()` method I thought to make a page copy before merging, but for some reasons it uses the same page and I got my text printed several times.

How can I avoid that?

**My code**:

```
packet = io.BytesIO()
can = canvas.Canvas(packet)
can.drawString(0,0, "Print on page 1")
can.showPage()
can.drawString(200,200, "Print on page 2")
can.showPage()
can.drawString(0,0, "Print on page 3")
can.showPage()
can.drawString(200,200, "Print on page 4")
can.save()

new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)

path_of_two_page_pdf = 'overview.pdf'
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(file(path_of_two_page_pdf, "rb"))

output = PdfFileWriter()
for pi in range(4):
    page = existing_pdf.getPage(pi % 2)
    page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(pi))
    output.addPage(page)

outputStream = file("NEW_PDF.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: can you link to the input files so I can have a further look?

Comment: @B8vrede I don't see why this downvote. Any PDF with two pages will be good (I draw different strings on each page).

Comment: But as I just fixed that part I removed the downvote

Comment: @B8vrede Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getPage()` actually return the pointer to the page instead of a completely new page. So when `mergePage()` is applied it merge it into the existing pdf.

The easiest workaround is to first create a blank page and use that to merge the other pages onto, that will look like this:

```
for pi in range(2*2):
    # By doing this we will always create a blank page with the same size as the last page of the existing_pdf
    new_page = PageObject.createBlankPage(pdf=existing_pdf)

    # Merge the pages onto the blank page
    new_page.mergePage(existing_pdf.getPage(pi % 2))
    new_page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(pi))

    # Add the new page to the output
    output.addPage(new_page)
```

One note, instead of creating a completely separate blank page using `createBlankPage` you could also use `output.addBlankPage` but this requires setting the page size manually which might not be ideal. Therefor the `pdf` keyword of `createBlankPage` is used, this sets the page size to the last page of the supplied pdf.

Answer (score 0):

As @B8vrede mensioned above `addBlankPage` can be used, so instead of creating a separate blank page I called  `addBlankPage` (which returns a reference to the new created page) specifying the `A4` size.

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4


for pi in range(4):
    new_page = output.addBlankPage(*A4)
    new_page.mergePage(existing_pdf.getPage(pi % 2))
    new_page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(pi))
```